# Laravel Crontab + Shell Exec

Tags: php, laravel, cron, shell-exec

I have a Laravel App with Short Schedule package installed and a crontab to execute it.

Inside the executed method I have a SHELL_EXEC function with some code inside it.

The problem is that when the code runs automatically using the cron, the SHELL EXEC doesn't work. The output is null.

When I run the method directly using php artisan or by simply running the schedule using php artisan manually, it works.

To have a clear vision of what's going on:

Inside the crontab -e I have the following

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/project/artisan short-schedule:run --lifetime=60`

The cron executes this method which has the following code:

```
$shell_command = '/home/paul/elrondsdk/erdpy --verbose tx new --receiver xxxx --send --pem asdfa.pem --gas-limit 300 --nonce 12';

$output = shell_exec($shell_command);

Log::info('output', [$output]);
```

***If it runs automatically using the cron, the $output is NULL.
If I run the command manually, I get a proper output.***

Initially I thought I need to specify the exact path in the shell exec because cron doesn't not PATH. Unfortunately did not solve my problem.

Thanks!

I tried to run the command manually or to run php artisan schedule:run and wait and it worked!

It doesn't work ONLY when its runs by the cron.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `asdfa.pem` is referenced in `erdpy`. Make sure that uses the full file path instead just the filename.

Comment: Please read all the post :) That's the error I want to get actually if the command runs by the crontab.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I misunderstood.

Comment: No worries. Let me know if you have any ideas!